# What criteria should I follow to choose a Windows version, to run Mathematica 10.0 or higher?

Tags: system-performance

I must install Mathematica 10.4 on a PC, running Windows, specially intended for this job (basically, no other software will be used there).

I'm quite free about choosing the OS (Windows 7, 8, 10, etc.), but I  haven't well founded criteria.

As a rule of thumb, taking in account the narrow mission of the system, I speculate that the best fitting OS should be capable to squeeze the hardware without overburdening the machine with unwanted (and here totally unnecessary) features.

Please, can you give any hints arising from practical examination ?

Comment: Is your computer 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Hi ! It's 64 bit.

Comment: See http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html and http://support.wolfram.com/kb/6479

Comment: Keeping in mind that this is just one data point: I normally would recommend a Linux machine since a lot of Linux distributions are cruftless, relative to WIndows, but since *Mathematica* graphics in Linux still leaves a lot to be desired, I would consider getting a tool for stripping out unneeded/unwanted Windows components. ([This](https://www.ntlite.com/) is one such tool, but you can certainly find others by searching.) The reason why I haven't posted this as an answer is that my experience with such tools is 6 or so years outdated, and I don't know if they're still okay for Windows 10.

Comment: I'm going to investigate in Windows forums and I will share the  outcome here.